# Unable to get the NAME property from the DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, dom

I am unable to get the `name` attribute directly as a property of a DOM object.

As seen from a screenshot of Chrome Developer Tools, there is no property called `name` for a typical `div` object:

[image]

Am I missing something basic?

Comment: name gets or sets the name property of a DOM object; **it only applies to the following elements**: `<a>`, `<applet>`, `<button>`, `<form>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<map>`, `<meta>`, `<object>`, `<param>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name

Comment: @JaromandaX - Note that [fieldset](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#ref-for-dom-interface-99) and [embed](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/obsolete.html#ref-for-htmlembedelement-htmlembedelement-1) are incorrectly absent from that list.

Comment: @Alohci - to be 100% accurate, `embed` does **not** have `name` attribute in the HTML5 spec - the link you've posted is to the 15 day old HTML5.1 "W3C recommendation" - but yes, `<fieldset>` is missing in that MDN list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element.getAttribute('name')` and it will return value of `name` attribute from any elements.

Comment: Thanks.  Surprisingly this works, even though `name` is not a DHTML property as Jaromanda X mentioned.

Comment: yes, it works - your question was about Developer Tools

Comment: I tested, and jQuery's `attr` method will return successfully the value of *any* attribute (including anything not in the specifications) I add to the Html mark-up.